# Gitlab CE: gitaly['gitconfig'] has been deprecated since 15.10 and was removed in 16.0

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

Before asking question I have reviewed the existing solutions, but it wasn't that helpful.

I want to upgrade the Gitlab Community Edition (Gitlab CE) from version `15.11.11` to `16.1.2`. Whenever I run the `sudo apt install gitlab-ce=16.1.2-ce.0`, I face to the following error:

> gitaly['gitconfig'] has been deprecated since 15.10 and was removed in 16.0. In GitLab 15.10, Gitaly's configuration in Omnibus GitLab was changed to structurally match Gitaly's own configuration. Please see the migration instructions at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#15100
> Deprecations found. Please correct them and try again.

I have also checked the link (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#15100) that it has mentioned in that error trace, but I didn't find anything helpful.
How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For those who encounter a similar problem, I recommend checking their `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file and the following solution. This may be helpful.

The issue was resolved by checking the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file. The error message was somewhat misleading, as I was searching for a key named `gitaly['gitconfig']` but couldn’t find any related key. Instead, I found a variable named `omnibus_gitconfig['system']`. The error message indicated that configuring GitLab in this manner is deprecated. As a result, I commented out the configuration and reloaded it using the `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command.

Finally, I simply ran `sudo apt install gitlab-ce=16.1.2-ce.0` and it works as expected.